# JS function removing old properties from object instead of adding to them

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I created an object in JS called filterObj like this

```
var filterObj={};
```

The problem is that if I add property to the object, it adds but it removes the previous ones. In fact it takes the root filterObj which is empty, not the edited one.

In which I have two functions:

```
function handleGovernorate(Governorate) {
    if (Governorate === "") {
        return
    }
    else if (Governorate === "all") {
        delete filterObj.governorate;
        handleFilterObj();
        return setFinalLocations(Locations);
    }
    else {
        filterObj.governorate = Governorate;
        handleFilterObj();
    }
}

function handleGovernorate(District) {
    if (District === "") {
        return
    }
    else if (District === "all") {
        delete filterObj.district;
        handleFilterObj();
        return setFinalLocations(Locations);
    }
    else {
        filterObj.district = District;
        handleFilterObj();
    }
}
```

If I call `handleGovernorate("mountLB")` it sets the property governorate with value mountLB, but if I then call `handleDistrict("2")` the function will set a property district with value 2 but with removing the governorate property - why?

Comment: I cleaned your code a bit - please format your code correctly when asking, it makes it much easier to understand :) 

Alsso, what do the `handleFilterObj` and `setFinalLocations` functions do?

Comment: Thanks, handleFilterObj takes the object 'filterObj' then transform it to keys and values then uses the filter function to find matches in the original json array of objects called Locations, and finally set the setFinalLocations as the result. setFinalLocations is a usestate statement to set the final Locations that appears on a graphical map.

Comment: I'm sorry I had to write it instead of giving a code since I'm out of office right now

Comment: But handleFilterObj looks something like this: ```  const handleFilterObj= (filterObj) => {
  const matchEntries = Object.entries(filterObj);
  return Locations.filter(item => {
    return matchEntries.every(([key, val]) => item[key] === val);
  });
};
```

Comment: I then changed the filterObj object to a useState and it worked, but why didn't it work using the old declaration statement of an object? It renders 3 or 4 times when I execute any function. Do you have any idea??